# How to add width constrain using constraintsWithVisualFormat while already using constraintsWithVisualFormat for vertical spacing between two view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I am new to IOS and I am adding constrain to my added view with using constraintsWithVisualFormat. I already use constraintsWithVisualFormat to have vertical spacing by these following code:-

```
    self.underlineConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint 
    constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[view]-80-[underlineView(5)]" 
    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing 
    metrics:nil views:views];
```

Here 5 is height of underlineView and 80 is space between two views but I want to add constrain of width of underlineView 150.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add width constraints:

```
[self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint 
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[underlineView(150)]"
                            options: kNilOptions
                            metrics:nil views:views]];
```